# Unit test Angular directive with injected service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

How can I unit test this directive which makes an $http call out to `MyService`? How do I mock out or spy on `MyService` properly?

```
  angular.module('example')
    .directive('myDirective', ['MyService', function(MyService) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/myDirective.html',
        scope: {
          name: '@',
          required: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, billingCtrl) {
          scope.data = [];

          MyService.get()
            .then(function(res) {
              scope.data = res;
            });
        }
      };
    }]);
```

**My test:**

```
  describe('Directive: <my-directive>', function() {
    // setup code
    beforeEach(module('example'));

    var element;
    var compile;
    var scope;
    var compiledElementScope;
    var validTemplate = '<my-directive ng-model="testModel" name="test"></my-directive>';
    var MyService = { get: function() {} };
    var $q;

    function getCompiledElement(template) {
      var compiledElement;

      compiledElement = compile(template || validTemplate)(scope);
      scope.$digest();

      return compiledElement;
    }

    beforeEach(function() {
      module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value('MyService', MyService);
      });

      inject(function($compile, $rootScope, _$q_) {
        compile = $compile;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $q = _$q_;
      });

    });

    describe('my directive', function() {
      var element;

      beforeEach(function() {
        element = getCompiledElement(validTemplate);
      });

      it('should make a call to MyService and update scope.data', function() {
        // how do I asset the following
        expect(scope.data).toEqual(...);
      });
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing `var MyService = { get: function() {} };` create a spy object inside the `beforeEach` where you apply the mock service to the provider.

Something like this should work:
    var MyService;

```
beforeEach(function() {
  MyService = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['get']);

  MyService.get = jasmine.createSpy('get').and.callFake(function () {
        return {
            then: function (callback) {
                callback(<RETURN_DATA>);
                return this;
            }
        };
    });

  module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('MyService', MyService);
  });

  ... 

});
```

For `<RETURN_DATA>` just return the mock result you expect being saved into `scope.data`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use ng-mock's $httpBackend service.

This service allows you to EXPECT an http request to be made and to mock the response.

If the request is not made then the test fails.

$httpBackend.when ... this says IF an http request is made then respond as follows ... there is no expectation and thus IF the request is not made the test will not fail.

$httpBackend.flush() says make any pending requests now. It will fail if there are no requests pending.

Don't forget ...

```
afterEach(function () {
  httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
  httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

Finally, $httpBackend will complain if requests are made for HTML files dynamically. To avoid this pre-load all HTML files in your karma.conf.js

```
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/!(*spec)*.js': ['coverage'],
      'dest/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },
    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'dest/',
      moduleName: 'ngHtmlFiles'
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      type: 'html',
      dir: 'coverage'
    },
    files: [
      'dest/vendor.min.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'src/**/*.js',
      'dest/**/*.html'
    ]
```

I know this config setup is a pain but if you want to follow industry practice then you need to get this working :)